# Vertical scroll bar on Users page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

When filtering the users, if the filter doesn't return any results, a vertical scroll appears. This happens in all major browsers on Mac.

**Edit:**
Added a second screenshot with Chrome (v14) and Firefox (v6). The OS is 10.6.8 and the screen resolution is 1440 x 900.

[image]

[image]

Comment: can't repro in Safari/Win, at least...

Comment: I cannot repro this in Chrome/Safari/FF OSX

Comment: @Jeff I've added additional screenshots and details to the original post.

Comment: I see it in Chrome (v14), Safari Version 5.0.5 (6533.21.1), Firefox 3.6.19 on MACOS 10.6.8. It only occurs when there are no users to show for the given section. For example on meta, this week, editors.

Comment: @Alex: Does this issue still exist?

Comment: @Barry It doesn't seems so; I can't reproduce it at the moment, so it was probably solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be have been resolved.